# VBA instruction not functioning the same as manual editing for arc shape nodes

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using this piece of code for what I will explain below:

```vb
Sub TEST_ARC_SETTINGS()

    Dim Arc_Shape As Shape

    Set Arc_Shape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeArc, 50, 50, 100, 100)

     With Arc_Shape

        .Adjustments.Item(1) = -45

        .Adjustments.Item(2) = 0

     End With

     'FIRST SCREENSHOT

     Arc_Shape.Nodes.SetEditingType 5, msoEditingCorner

     Arc_Shape.Fill.ForeColor = VBA.RGB(200, 200, 200)

     Set Arc_Shape = Nothing

     'SECOND SCREENSHOT

End Sub
```

SNAPSHOTS:
When running the code to "FIRST SCREENSHOT":
[Arc Shape with Shape size reflecting that of circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f01wY.png)
When completing the code:
[When setting the node property to what it is, the arc size changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqkO7.png)
Now doing manually what I had hoped VBA would do:
[When manually selecting what has been done in VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO9OY.png)

[The size of the object changes to what it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Abxl.png)

[This is what I want to achieve - the arc is "locked" and the object size is smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJNPz.png)

I've tried different options to manipulate the nodes of the object in VBA, and they all resize the arc, unlike when doing it manually.  I expected the VBA instructions to render what I could achieve manually.

Comment: The line that is causing the problem is `Arc_Shape.Nodes.SetEditingType 5, msoEditingCorner`. Take that out and you get much closer to what you want.

Comment: The problem is that the line that is "causing the problem" is exactly the command that I need to render that which happens when doing the same thing manually (unless there is an alternative).  When editing the points of the object manually, and "changing" the type of one of the points to the same value it already has, it causes the size of the object to reduce to the size of the arc (and disallows changing the angles with it).  This is exactly what I want.  But the VBA code changes the size of the arc to the size of the object, and not the other way around as when doing it manually.

Comment: I considered using a freeform shape to draw an arc as an alternative, but the problem is that I cannot (as far as I know) fill the drawn shape as a sector of a circle rather than the shape of a circle segment.  However, if I use a sector shape, it has radii lines along with the arc, which I don't want.  The reason why I need to the "smaller than the circle" object size that I can obtain manually, is because I plot arcs in a canvas, and sometimes, while the arc itself is within the canvas, the object itself based on the circle associated with the arc, does not fit into the canvas.

Comment: If the above cannot be resolved, is there any way to report it for Microsoft developers to look into it? Otherwise, I suppose that I would have to settle for a workaround (requiring quite a bit of coding). For the above, one could resize the object as follows: 
Arc_Shape.Height = VBA.Sin(45 / 180 * 3.14159) 
Arc_Shape.Width = 50 
For this particular example, it would yield what I want. But for any random angle size and rotation (as in my application), one would have to consider the quadrants across which the arc stretches, etc., and readjust the position of the object as well.